# How does gmail work under the hood

Tags: gmail

Just out of curiosity, I'm wondering how gmail does what it does. After looking in the source of the page you don't see any links, onclick methods and javascript. I understand they hide the javascript, but still the page knows that there was a click. Is there a daemon thread running that listens for your clicks? How does it work??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit old now but here's an article kind of explaining Gmail under the hood: http://johnvey.com/features/gmailapi/ (see section "About the Gmail engine and protocol")

> The item most relevant to this project
>   is what I refer to as the “DataPack”,
>   a base HTML file that contains only
>   JavaScript array declarations that the
>   UI engine parses and then uses to
>   determine what to update. The
>   advantages of this should be
>   immediately obvious: reduced traffic
>   load, and increased functionality —
>   especially for developers who no
>   longer have to resort to crude “screen
>   scraping” techniques to interface with
>   web applications. Although the ideal
>   situation for external developers
>   would be an XML-based DataPack, the
>   JavaScript version is sufficient (and
>   I suspect it was chosen for
>   performance reasons as well).
>
> The DataPack format consists of
>   individual “DataItems”, or JavaScript
>   arrays wrapped in a envelope function.
>   An example:
>
> `D(["ts",0,50,106,0,"Inbox","fd36721220",154]);`

Wikipedia's entry is pretty good at a brief overview too: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail_interface

Comment: the first link is dead.
..didn't think about wikipedia.. but it's a bit shallow..

Comment: And here we have the problem of linkrot and relying on an external site for the bulk of an answer.

Comment: The DataPack format is replaced by some super-array a few years ago. Just have a look at the source of a Gmail page and look for "VIEW_DATA"

Comment: I've made this post into a Community Wiki so it can be edited as the info is already out of date!